# Testing an existing macro doesn't work

Tags: beamer, macros, overlays

Once defined, I don't want the macro `\Stepx` be redefined :

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,professionalfont,french]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier,tikz,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usetheme{Madrid}               % thème
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=white, bg=MidnightBlue!90}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=MidnightBlue!15}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=1 mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=1 mm}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\makeatletter
\def\c@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\def\beamerslideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\MyLabel}[1]{%
\ifcsname Step#1\endcsname%
\else%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname Step#1\endcsname{\arabic{slideinframe}}%
\fi%
}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=bob]{Title}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item \only<.>{\MyLabel{a}}\arabic{slideinframe}

    \Stepa

\item \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item
    \item 
    \end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't work, the last question was vague but this one is even harder to guess the problem. only you know what you want it to do, so "does not work" gives no information to anyone else. The `\mylabel` is only executed once, the stepa is undefined so it gets defined. What else do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want Stepa still 1 on every slide. Sorry not to be enought explicative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using the commands from `etoolbox`.  In particular, there is `\ifcsdef` and `\csxdef` usable here as.  Note you need `xdef` as you want the definition expanded at the time the command is defined.  The `gdef` version will just set the command to `\arabic{slideinframe}` which changes with each frame.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\MyLabel}[1]{%
\ifcsdef{Step#1}{}{\csgdef{Step#1}{\arabic{slideinframe}}}}
```

You completed document is then:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,professionalfont,french]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier,tikz,ifthen}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usetheme{Madrid}               % thème
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=white, bg=MidnightBlue!90}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=MidnightBlue!15}

\setbeamersize{text margin left=1 mm}
\setbeamersize{text margin right=1 mm}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\makeatletter
\def\c@slideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\def\beamerslideinframe{\beamer@slideinframe}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\MyLabel}[1]{%
\ifcsdef{Step#1}{}{\csxdef{Step#1}{\arabic{slideinframe}}}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[label=bob]{Title}
\begin{enumerate}[<+->]
\item \only<.>{\MyLabel{a}}\arabic{slideinframe}

    \Stepa

\item \begin{itemize}[<+->]
    \item
    \item 
    \end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew, but the command still be redefined as after the first slide it becomes 2 then 3 then 4. I want it still be 1 as initially defined.

Comment: OK - you need `xdef` not `gdef` instead.  Answer updated.